# JavaScript onclick event doesnt work with parameters

Tags: javascript

So i have a button with this event attached:

```
apagar.onclick = cl.teste(this);
```

cl is an instance of another class , i think it doesnt matter to this case.
The teste method is here:

```
Clinica.prototype.teste = function ()
{
    alert(this.doentes.length);
}
```

even when i have some parameters on the function, and i set them on the onclick event, the button just does nothing. But, when i set it like this: apagar.onclick = cl.teste; it works. 
I need the arguement because i need the 'this' statement to work properly for the object and not for the event.

Comment: Could you provide a working example, e.g. on jsfiddle?

Comment: `apagar.addEventListener('click', cl.teste.bind(cl), false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
apagar.onclick = cl.teste(this);
```

You can write:

```
apagar.onclick = function () {
    cl.teste(apagar);
};
```

The `onclick` event can be attached to a function not to a function-call. Here `cl.teste` is a function, while `cl.tests(this)` is a function call. With my workaround, it should work.

Comment: Yes, onclick is an event handler, not a property!

Comment: yea i just did that before reading this post ! ty for help :) it worked !

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the question, but I think `this.doentes.length` is a property on `cl`. So you would use `cl.teste(cl)` here, not `cl.teste(apagar)`.

Comment: i used: apagar.addEventListener('click', function () { cl.removerDoente(this);});

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bind` in this situation:

```
apagar.onclick = cl.teste.bind(cl);
```